# stray letter before HTML in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

This is quite specific but hopefully, might shed some light on how Laravel generates pages.

Suddenly I have a stray 'j' being generated above all the code on every page of the site. it's nothing to to with the blade templates as it even displays when I return text from the routes. eg

```
    Route::any('test', function()
   {
        return 'hello';
    });
```

returns

```
    jhello
```

Probably embarrassingly obvious but it's stumped me!

Comment: Somewhere in one of your files, before the opening php tag or even after a closing php tag, you likely typed a `j`.  Go into your php.ini file and set `output_buffering` to `Off`, restart your server, and try running your app again, it might give you a clue as to where it is.

Comment: most likely before or after closing the `}}`

Comment: Check your config files. I usually find my misplaced letters there

Comment: Thank you all folks, that's exactly where it was. (Session.php in my case).  Still not sure how that would get rendered and not throw an error but that may be above my pay grade. How do I accept this?